# Is it possible have the font of Harry Potter in Latex?

Tags: fonts

It might seem like a silly question, but is there a way to have a font very similar to the font used in Harry Potter ? Something like this:

[[image: Harry Potter's font1]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: If it's a standard TrueType font you can download, install in your OS, then use it in LaTeX. E.g., `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{HarryPotter}` and compile with xelatex or lualatex.